# Let $p(t)$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}$. Defining $p_0(t) = p(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $p(t)$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}$. Defining $p_0(t) = p(t), p_1(t) = 1 + \int_0^t p_0(s)ds, ... , p_k = 1+ \int_0^t p_{k-1}(s)ds.$ Prove that $p_k(t)$ converges uniformly on each compact interval of $\mathbb{R}$ when $k \rightarrow \infty.$ Compute $lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} p_k(t).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that $p_0=c_0+c_1x+\cdots +c_nx^n$. Then $$p_1=1+c_0x+c_1{x^2\over 2}+\cdots +c_n{x^{n+1}\over {n+1}}$$ so $$p_2=1+x+c_0{x^2\over 2}+c_1{x^3\over 2(3)}+\cdots +c_n{x^{n+2}\over (n+1)(n+2)}$$ In general, noting that we can write $$a(a+1)\cdots (a+b)=\frac{(a+b)!}{(a-1)!}$$ it seems that $$p_k=\bigg(1+\cdots+{x^{k-1}\over (k-1)!}\bigg)+\bigg(c_0\frac{0!\,x^k}{k!}+c_1\frac{1!\,x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}+c_2\frac{2!\,x^{k+2}}{(k+2)!}+\cdots\bigg)$$ from which is looks like $p_k\to e^x$ as $k\to\infty$.

You could show that the second term goes to zero as $k\to\infty$, or perhaps there is a theorem in differential equations which comes to mind.